# Server is not responding when ajax request length is big wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am facing a problem with ajax request to admin-ajax.php.

When request content length is less e.g 3000. server response is 200. it is working fine.

But when request content length is e.g. 300000. server response is 302. it is redirecting to another page without responding.

I don't know what is happening. I am on shared server. Can I do anything using cpanel?

Can anyone help me please?

thanks

Comment: Check your `max_input_vars` and `post_max_size`, if the hosting provider allow it you can change it in the settings or override it with `ini_set` in your php file or in your .htacces file with `php_value`

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following, that solves my problem. However, it's recommended that you use chunk data if you can like loading a specific number of data for a request.

Method 1: Put `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300)` top of your ajax file(300 seconds)

Method 2: Change server configuration/Edit php.ini

```
– upload_max_filesize = 265M
– post_max_size = 265M
– max_input_time = -1
– max_input_vars = 8000
– max_execution_time = 500
– Memory Limit = 512M
```